# Multicasting with a Debian Router

Tags: debian, networking, router, multicast

I have a local network and I want to use NTP in multicast mode on this LAN. The first step to do this is to get multicast networking to work first.

In the network I have 5 Debian machines all connected to a a Debian router with 5 network interfaces. I installed mrouted on the router but when I try to ping 224.0.0.1 from any machine I only got answers from the machine itself and the router. The router don't seem to forward the multicast packet.

What should I do to make it work ?

Comment: try running some simple python programs mentioned in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/603852/5008284).